# Authenticate before calling REST endpoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http

I'm trying to get an authentication token from my REST API before calling any other endpoint (preferably once). 
For this I created a token factory that calls the login and receives a token back. I then expect to inject that token factory into my other controllers. I was hoping that the dependencies where being respected but my controller calls the service before obtaining the token from the token factory. what did I do wrong ?

factory:

```
app.factory('tokenFactory', function($http, appConfig) {

    console.log('calling endpoint: ' + appConfig.REST_ENDPOINT + 'authentication/login');

    var apiToken;

    $http.post(appConfig.REST_ENDPOINT + 'authentication/login', { 
        "username": "john",
        "password": "open$esame" 
    }).
    success(function(data) {
        apiToken = data.token;
    }).
    error(function(data) {
        //
    });

    return {
        apiToken: apiToken
    };
});
```

controller:

```
app.controller('clientListCtrl', function($scope, $http, appConfig, tokenFactory) {

    console.log('calling endpoint: ' + appConfig.REST_ENDPOINT+'/client/list');

    $http.get(appConfig.REST_ENDPOINT+'/client/list', { 
        header: { 'Authorization': tokenFactory.apiToken }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.clients = data;    
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            //
        });
});
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Side note: I wouldn't consider your API fully RESTful because of how your login API call is structured. I recommend you POST (or PUT) to a resource for "authentication," rather than just POSTing to an endpoint. That way you can later add functionality for an administrative view that gives you query functionality by GETing that resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to take into account the asynchronous aspect of Ajax and leverage promise chaining (the `$http.post` actually returns a promise that you need to return). The factory will use the method `getToken` can define a `success` method to be notified when the result is received.

```
app.factory('tokenFactory', function($http, appConfig) {
    console.log('calling endpoint: ' + appConfig.REST_ENDPOINT + 'authentication/login');

    return {
      getToken: function() {
        return $http.post(appConfig.REST_ENDPOINT + 'authentication/login', { 
          "username": "john",
          "password": "open$esame" 
        }).
        success(function(data) {
          return data.token;
        }).
        error(function(data) {
          //
        });
      }
    };
});
```

That said, I think that you should leverage the HTTP interceptor feature of Angular. This allows to transparently set the security token within your request. The first time the token is gotten using AJAX and then you can reuse this one.

```
app.factory('securityTokenInterceptor', function($q, tokenFactory) {  
  var currentToken = null;
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      if (currentToken != null) {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = currentToken;
        return config;
      }

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      tokenFactory.getToken().then(function(token) {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = token.token;
        currentToken = token.token;
        deferred.resolve(config);
      }, function(err) {
        // Handle error (reject promise, ...)
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
})
```

Here is the way to register your interceptor on `$httpProvider`:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('securityTokenInterceptor');
})
```

Here is the fake factory I use to get token:

```
app.factory('tokenFactory', function($q, $timeout) {
  return {
    getToken: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve({token:'mytoken'});
      }, 500);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
})
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

**In your factory:**
`$http.post()` is asynchronous, so the return after it will not contain the data coming from the post request. I would suggest returning the promise object you get from calling `$http.post()`.

**In your controller:** you can use the returned promise and define the success method, in which you can do the get request.

```
tokenFactory.success(function (tokenData) {
  token = tokenData.token;
  $http.get(endpoint, { header: { 'auth': token } })
    .success(...)
    .error(...);
});
```

Not sure if it is the best way how to do it, but I think it could work this way.

Comment: I've just noticed... Angular promises use .then() and .catch() instead of .success() and .error()

Comment: your suggestion would work but that means that each controller using the tokenFactory is going to authenticate and generate a new token. I was hoping for something where I authenticate once and then use that same token all over